# Mystery ghost page not appearing in Admin

Tags: permalinks, pages, admin

I have a strange problem.

I have a blog listing page like example.com/something but this page is no where to be found in the admin.

It returns 200 OK http status so its there.

But it uses a seemingly random template and looks broken.

What can I do?

How can I find it in admin?

The usual tricks dont work.

- There is no id to be found in the HTML source (no shortlink etc)
- searching for the permaling slug in admin doesnt return anything

What else could I try?

Comment: Is there a file named `something` or perhaps `something/index.html` residing in your site's root directory?  IE, in the filesystem, outside of the WordPress system entirely?

Comment: Or a plugin is adding it. Disable your plugins. Is it still there?

Comment: tried, its still there. no dir named like that either

Comment: i deactivated and reactivated plugins and found it! strangely though it doesnt accept the chosen template :/

Comment: ok, i edited the permalink to something2, made new page /something and the new page redirects to old url?!

Comment: You are providing bits and pieces of disjointed information. That is not enough to really tell what is happening.

Comment: Problem is Im not sure what is happening... For now it seems there is a certain SEO plugin messing things up. I was able to fix the problem, but not sure why this happens still

Comment: Perhaps you can take a look at the `body` tag within the source code of the page and check the `class` names. Perhaps it is an _archive_ or _taxonomy_ with an unexpected template?

Comment: thats a very smar suggestion and youre right, I found the ID there! I also found the problem it was a SEO plugin screwing with the permalinks. Thy to all the tipps you saved me many hours!

Comment: You should provide the solution below, to help others who come along. Specifically state which plugin it was, what it did to the permalinks, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested, it was the SEOyoast plugin that caused the problem.

I turned it off and on, than the page appeared again in the admin.

After that I rest the settings for the page and it now works as expected and accepts its template.